# will the following xerces code cause a memory leak?

Tags: c++, xerces, xerces-c

I have taken a look at an example i found on the internet of xerces  generating XML. The Transcode function seems to perform some encoding but the buffer it populates to is never released. According to the documentation you must release ti manually:

> NOTE: The returned buffer is dynamically allocated and is the responsibility of the caller to delete it when not longer needed. You can call XMLString::release to release this returned buffer.

could doc->release be releasing this from memory?

```
    XMLCh tempStr[100];

    XMLString::transcode("Range", tempStr, 99);
    DOMImplementation* impl = DOMImplementationRegistry::getDOMImplementation(tempStr, 0);

    XMLString::transcode("root", tempStr, 99);
    DOMDocument*   doc = impl->createDocument(0, tempStr, 0);
    DOMElement*   root = doc->getDocumentElement();

    XMLString::transcode("FirstElement", tempStr, 99);
    DOMElement*   e1 = doc->createElement(tempStr);
    root->appendChild(e1);

    XMLString::transcode("SecondElement", tempStr, 99);
    DOMElement*   e2 = doc->createElement(tempStr);
    root->appendChild(e2);
    doc->release();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forgive me if I've misunderstood, but the version of `transcode` you're using there doesn't actutally create or return any buffers, because it is modifying the one you've supplied (`tempStr`) in place. Your example code will not leak memory.

The versions of `transcode` which *do* return a buffer (eg. every other version except the ones in your example code block) use a `MemoryManager` instance to perform the allocation. The documentation seems a little sparse here, but as far as I can tell the default `XMLPlatformUtils::fgMemoryManager` makes no claims to clean up any memory it has allocated. You should therefore assume that you need to destroy that returned buffer yourself.

Answer (score 1):

No, `doc->release()` is not releasing the buffer.

As the documentation you quoted says, you *would* need to release the buffer with `XMLString::release()`, if you were calling a `transcode` function that returns a transcoded string:

```
char *str = XMLString::transcode(someStringVarToBeTranscoded);
XMLString::release(&str);
```

Your example does not need to do this, because you are using a `transcode` function that returns a `boolean` value.

Comment: so if i call transcode on the same buffer twice and only call release once will it cause a memory leak?

Comment: @godzilla: No. In your example, you do not need to worry about releasing a buffer. Your buffer, `tempStr[100]`, is allocated on the **stack**. Once this function goes out of scope, the buffer will be released.

Comment: @godzilla: I have also updated my answer a bit to clarify things.

Comment: Doug one last thing, there is little documentation regarding createTextNode also, will the DOMText * it returns need to be deallocated or will doc>release() do that for you?

Comment: @godzilla: From the [documentation](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/ApacheDOMC++Binding.html#release): "*The C++ DOM implementation provides a release() method for releasing any "orphaned" resources that were created through createXXXX factory method. Memory for any returned object are owned by implementation.*"